# Timing Audio with precision / Lag with Firefox setInterval and setting currentTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, audio

I am writing a JS app that highlights words in sync with pre-recorded audio. The process is pretty simple. I have list of the times when each word starts in the audio, and I call a JS function every .1 seconds to check audio.currentTime and see if it has reached the threshold of the next word. I have tried using the audio timeUpdate event, and doesn't get triggered frequently enough across platforms for my purposes. Words get skipped.

I've tested my code on a Moto E in mobile Chrome, an iPad (mobile Safari), a Kindle Fire (silk browser or whatever they call it now), and on Windows in the latest Chrome, Firefox and IE 11.

It all works pretty well with one exception: Firefox lags. The syncing works fine at first in FF, but each time I cue the audio to a new time, Firefox seems to  fall behind, and by the 10th page or so (even if I just skip right to it by pressing my "next page" button repeatedly), the lag is noticeable. The narrator will be finishing one word and FF will just start highlighting the previous one.

Here's the relevant code:

This gets called once the AJAX call for the book information comes back:

```
window.setInterval( bundleFunctions.execute, 100 );
```

The `bundleFunctions` object is just a simple way to call a dynamic group of functions at the same time.

There are two functions that get added to `bundleFunctions`. The one I'm concerned about is `highlightWord`.

```
var lasthighlight = -1;
function highlightWord() {

    var debug = false;

        // find the last word time that comes before the current time.

    var playerSound     = document.getElementById( "playerSound" );     // audio tag

        // wordTimes is an array of times where each word starts in the recorded audio

    var indexToHighlight = Math.max.apply( Math, $.map( wordTimes, function( time, index ) {

            // only highlight words that start before the current time with a buffer equal to the interval at which this function is called
            // don't highlight word for more than 2 seconds.

        if ( time - .1 > playerSound.currentTime || playerSound.currentTime - time > 2 ) {      
            return null;

            // if this is the last or first wordTime or the preceding word time
            // is less than the current time, return the index of that word time

        } else {
            return index;
        }
    }));

        // minimize lag by not touching the DOM if there's no new word to highlight

    if ( typeof indexToHighlight != "undefined" ) {
        if ( lasthighlight != indexToHighlight ) {
            lasthighlight = indexToHighlight;

            if ( debug ) {
                console.log( "highlighting word [ " + $( ".word.use:eq(" + indexToHighlight + ")" ).text() + "] at this index: [" + indexToHighlight + "]" );
                console.log( indexToHighlight );
            }
            $word = $( ".word:eq(" + indexToHighlight + ")");
            $( ".word" ).css( "color", "black" );
            $word.css( "color", "red" );
        } 
    }
}
```

You can see I added some code to try to minimize DOM manipulation in the hope that that was the reason FF was falling behind, but it had no effect. Note that there is never more than 40 or so words on the page at once, so it's not like this is some heavy duty DOM manipulation, and the lag seems directly related to seeking in the audio, not to any issue the FF JS engine has handling its workload.

The other function that gets called by bundleFunction checks if we've reached the end of a page. Here is that function (`override` allows me to skip the the next page manually):

```
function checkAdvancePage( override ) {
    var debug = false;
    override = override === true;
    if ( playerSound.currentTime >= timeToSeconds( book.pages.page[ curPage ][ "_f" ]) || override ) {

        if ( book.pages.page.length >= curPage + 2 ) {
            if ( debug ) {
                console.log( "advancing page from [" + curPage + "]" );
            }

            curPage++;

            if ( debug ) {
                console.log( "to [" + curPage + "]" );
            }


                // this book has another page. Keep going.

            startPage( book );

        } else {

                // this book is on its last page

            endScreen( book );
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's pretty darn basic. 99.9% of the time it will evaluate one line of code -- "is currentTime > the current page's end time?", come back false, and end.

lastly, here is the code where, among other things, the code seeks in the audio  to the beginning of a new page on a change in pages. The weirdly structured book object is like that because it is converted from XML:

```
var soundLoaded = false;
var isPlaying   = false;
function queueAudio( book ) {
    var debug           = false;

    var playerSound     = document.getElementById( "playerSound" );     // audio tag
    var playing         = false;
    playerSound.addEventListener( 'canplaythrough', function queue() {

        if ( debug ) {
            console.log( "tracing this page" );
            console.log( book.pages.page[ curPage ]);   
        }

        playerSound.currentTime = timeToSeconds( book.pages.page[ curPage ]["_s" ]);
        playerSound.removeEventListener( 'canplaythrough', queue );
        bundleFunctions.add( checkAdvancePage );
        soundLoaded             = true;
    }); 


    if ( !soundLoaded ) {
        var playerSource    = document.getElementById( "playerSource" );    // source tag
        playerSource.src    = BOOKS_DIR + book.track[ "_src" ];
        playerSound.load();
        playerSound.play();         // has to be called here to link a mobile tap to the play command
        isPlaying = true;
    } else {
        playerSound.currentTime = timeToSeconds( book.pages.page[ curPage ]["_s" ]);
    }

        // manual click to next page. Only add the listener once.
    if ( typeof( document.getElementById( "next" ).onclick ) == "undefined" ) {
        $( "#next" ).click( function() {
            console.log( "next page clicked" );
            checkAdvancePage( true );
        });
    }

        // watches current time of audio and advances to the next page when we get to the end of the audio for that page

    function checkAdvancePage( override ) {
        var debug = false;
        override = override === true;  // if true, advance the page regardless of currentTime
        if ( playerSound.currentTime >= timeToSeconds( book.pages.page[ curPage ][ "_f" ]) || override ) {
            playerSound.removeEventListener( 'timeupdate', checkAdvancePage );

            if ( book.pages.page.length >= curPage + 2 ) {
                if ( debug ) {
                    console.log( "advancing page from [" + curPage + "]" );
                }

                curPage++;

                if ( debug ) {
                    console.log( "to [" + curPage + "]" );
                }


                    // this book has another page. Keep going.

                startPage( book );

            } else {

                    // this book is on its last page

                endScreen( book );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is acceptable if a word isn't highlight at the exact moment it is spoken. What is not acceptable is for a word to *become* highlighted *after* it has been spoken, which is starting to happen at fast parts of the audio about 10 pages in.

The quickest words are spoken in about .1 seconds. It would fine if once in a while, one of those super-quick words got skipped as long as the highlighting remained in sync.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.